# Print specific div without parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What i'm trying to accomplish is this:

I have a parent div which has multiple childs. I don't want to display the parent only the children. If I do this:

```
.navbar-default, #filters, #options {
display: none;
}
div#filter_date {
display: block;
}
```

Then it just doesn't show the the parent div with its children.

I have tried to make the question as easy as possible.

Comment: Can you post your html code ?

Comment: You can't do that, styles are inherited.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You cannot hide the parent element without hiding its children, but you might be able to resolve it in another way. Please supply more details about your specific problem.

Comment: Just a guess. `#parent :not(div#filter_date){display: none;}`

Comment: So in order to accomplish this I have to wright a lot more css? As my printing happens by media=print. To then dispose of everything I don't need by cutting it in really small pieces?

Comment: This is another guess, but I think it cannot be done: `$("#parent").siblings().css("background-color", "red");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot accomplish this the way you anticipate, as styles are inherited.

Your only solution would be to override the print styles for the parent to give the impression it was being hidden, e.g set any border to none, remove any background colors or images, remove padding, margin etc. Take whatever styles you have applied for the parent, and in your print CSS override them with properties which will provide the illusion the parent isnt in place.

Otherwise you are attempting to change the structure of your DOM with CSS alone, which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, I think you can use jQuery .unwrap if I understand properly what you're trying to achieve.

Adapted from jQuery's own example...

```
<div class="yellow">
<p class="in-out">Am I in the </p>
<p class="in-out">div or out</p>
<p class="in-out">the div</p>
</div>
....
<button>Toggle</button>

---JS---
var pTags = $( ".in-out" );
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    if ( pTags.parent().is( ".yellow" ) ) {
    pTags.unwrap();
    } 
else {
    pTags.wrap( "<div class='yellow'></div>" );
}
});    

.... 

---CSS---
.yellow
{
background-color: yellow;
}
```

See example here...http://jsfiddle.net/richf/8LvJZ/

Obviously you don't need the button in your case.